# Using Java: How to display on-screen keyboard in linux or mac

Tags: java, linux, macos, process

How can I display the on-screen keyboard in linux or mac ?

For windows can be done using this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime() .exec("cmd /C start C:/WINDOWS/osk.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this from Java, but on Linux you can use `xvkbd` for on screen keyboard. Running system process from Java is same as on Windows.

```
String[] command = new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "xvkbd -no-repeat >/dev/null 2>&1 &";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Maybe you'll have to tune the command to execute, I use this in a shell startup script on a terminal PC without mouse and keyboard.

There are other on screen keyboards for Linux, like `onboard` or `florence`, they differ in look, resource requirements and dependencies. I found `xvkbd` as the lightest.